# Fatal error: Call to undefined method stdClass::AddAddress() in PHP mailer

Tags: php, phpmailer

I'm trying to send an e-mail to multiple e-mail address in my database. Here is my current code.I need to have them query my database and send the e-mail to each e-mail address.It is  working but email was send to the first e-mail address only, and got an error "Fatal error: Call to undefined method stdClass::AddAddress()".Where am I going wrong here?

```
<?php
$elist = $database->getRows("SELECT * FROM `emails`");

foreach($elist as $emails){
        $frm = 'test@gmail.com';
        $sub = 'Weekly Work Report';
        ob_start();
        include_once('mail_content.php');
        $mail_body = ob_get_contents(); 
        ob_end_clean();
        $to = $emails['email'];
        $mailstatus = lm_mail('1', '2', $to, '3', $frm, 'HR', $sub, $mail_body);
if ($mailstatus == 'ok') {
$response->redirect('index.php?com_route=user_report');
} else {
    echo $mailstatus;
}
}
?>

function lm_mail($head_mid='',$head_mname='',$to_mid ,$to_mname='',$reply_mid,$reply_mname='',$subject,$body,$attachments='')
{

    include_once 'phpmailer/mail_config.php';
    if(SMTP_mail)
    {
        // Send SMTP Mails
        $mail->From =$head_mid ;  // From  Mail id
        $mail->FromName = $head_mname; // From  Name

        $mail->AddAddress($to_mid,$to_mname); // To Address
        $mail->AddReplyTo($reply_mid,$reply_mname); // From Address

        $mail->Subject=$subject;

        $mail->Body =  $mail_body.$body; //HTML Body
        $mail->AltBody = "This is the body when user views in plain text format"; //Text Body

        if(!$mail->Send())
        {
            return $mail->ErrorInfo;
        }
        else
        {
           return 'ok';
        }
    }
    else
    {
        $mail  = new PHPMailer(); // defaults to using php "mail()"
        $mail->AddReplyTo($reply_mid,$reply_mname); // Sender address
        $mail->AddReplyTo($reply_mid,$reply_mname); // replay to address

        $address = $to_mid;  // to addtesas
        $mail->AddAddress($address, $to_mname);

        $mail->Subject    = $subject;
        $mail->AltBody    = "To view the message, please use an HTML compatible email viewer!"; // optional, comment out and test

        $mail->MsgHTML($mail_body.$body);
        if(!$mail->Send())
        {
            return  $mail->ErrorInfo;
        }
        else { return  'ok'; }
    }
}
```

Comment: `$mail` isn't initialized if `SMTP_mail` is true.

Comment: don't use include inside the loop, and what's with ob_start() ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the first conditional of the `lm_mail` function call there is no object being instantiated.

```
if(SMTP_mail)
{
    // No $mail object?

    // Send SMTP Mails
    $mail->From =$head_mid ;  // From  Mail id
```

Try adding:

```
if(SMTP_mail)
{
   $mail = new PHPMailer();  // create a new object
   $mail->IsSMTP(); // enable SMTP

   // Have to manually set language if PHPMailer can't determine
   $mail->SetLanguage("en", 'includes/phpMailer/language/');
```

Comment: ok now that error was resolved.. But now got another error "Language string failed to load: recipients_failed"

Comment: Did you read the docs on how to use PHPMailer? A quick google search found that you need to specify a language. I updated post.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing you are using `SMTP`, because I don't see where `$mail` comes from.

Since one email is sending, my guess is that `phpmailer/mail_config.php` sets up a `$mail` object and sets the `SMTP_mail` constant, and then it goes out of scope after the first function call and the file is only included once so it doesn't get defined again.

After that it wasn't defined as a `PHPMailer` object, so it is cast as a `stdClass` when you do the object assignment `$mail->From = $head_mid`.

Try taking the code out of mail_config.php and replicating it in your send function, or add a function to mail_config.php that provides a factory to getting a `PHPMailer` object that is configured for your needs.